# display news products in a page accessible from the menu

Tags: magento-1.7, category, products, navigation, new-products

i would like to show my news products in a page accessible from the menu..
the version of my magento is 1.7.0.2

so i created a page named "news".
in tab design, i added this xml in the textarea (xml update layout):

```
'<reference name="content"><block type="catalog/product_new" name="product_new" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
  <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>10</category_id></action>
  <action method="setColumnCount"><column_count>6</column_count></action>
  <action method="setProductsCount"><count>0</count></action>
  <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
     <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" />
     <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>12</limit></action>
     <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>12</limit></action>
     <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>24</limit></action>
     <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>36</limit></action>
     <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>48</limit></action>
     <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
  </block>
  <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>6</count></action>
  <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action></block></reference>'
```

indeed i follow this tutorial : http://www.dnawebagency.com/displaying-new-products-in-magento-with-pagination/.

the problem is that this solution does not work.

On internet there are many solution to display them on the home page but not in a category page.

Thank you for all your help

Comment: Do you want to create a separate page or do you want your news products to display in a category page?

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps I have taken to display **New Products** in a Category Page:

**Step 1:**
Create products with the 2 attributes filled in as below in the screenshot:

[image]

**Step 2:**
Create a category under *Catalog > Manage Categories*. Navigate to the tab `Custom Design` and do as per the screenshot:

[image]

Custom Layout XML code as follows (Update `list.phtml` to `new.phtml`):

```
<reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_new" name="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">
      <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>10</category_id></action>
      <action method="setColumnCount"><column_count>6</column_count></action>
      <action method="setProductsCount"><count>0</count></action>
      <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
         <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" />
         <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>12</limit></action>
         <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>12</limit></action>
         <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>24</limit></action>
         <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>36</limit></action>
         <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>48</limit></action>
         <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
       </block>
       <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>6</count></action>
        <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

**Step 3:**
Navigate from the Top Menu to the Category Page and see the below screenshot:

[image]

Couple of points about **New Products** in Magento:

> 1. Default Products Count = 10, which you can override and edit the PHP itself or specify via XML (you will need to check how this is done).
> 2. For the pagination to work, you can use *catalog/product_list_toolbar*, but this will call the list.phtml content **There are no products matching the selection.**, which you might want to edit by creating a separate toolbar for
>    **New Products** for ex: `catalog/product_new_toolbar`

Let me know if this helps.

Happy Coding...